# How to implement escape Sequence in SDL

Tags: c++, graphics, sdl, iostream

I'm trying to use the STL library inside the SDL. but it gives me the error
 `"undeclared identifier"`
Is there any way I can use `"\n"`or even `cout<<endl;`
Can the function `SDL_WarpMouse`which places the mouse cursor on a desired location on screen help me with this. Because I want to put a tile on the next line sequence.
I hope you get the Question. Its very vague and messed up question though (sorry for that).

**EDIT:**

```
void putMap(SDL_Surface* tile, SDL_Surface* screen)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < 21; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < 60; x++)
        {
            if(maze[x][y] != '#')
            {
                apply_surface( x*10 , y*10 , tile, screen);
            }
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

`c:\documents and settings\administrator\my documents\visual studio 2008\projects\craptest\craptest\main.cpp(605) : error C2065: 'cout' : undeclared identifier`

`c:\documents and settings\administrator\my documents\visual studio 2008\projects\craptest\craptest\main.cpp(605) : error C2065: 'endl' : undeclared identifier`

This is my apply_surface function.

```
void apply_surface( int x, int y, SDL_Surface* source, SDL_Surface* destination )
{
    //Make a temporary rectangle to hold the offsets
    SDL_Rect offset;

    //Give the offsets to the rectangle
    offset.x = x;
    offset.y = y;

    //Blit the surface
    SDL_BlitSurface( source, NULL, destination, &offset );
}
```

Comment: "it gives me the error..."  _what_ gives you the error?  Post your code.  (Why post a question if you know that it is "vague and messed up?"  Fix the question before you post it.)

Comment: How to get cout and endl to work is answered by @James McNellis. But what would be the sense in outputting a newline to the console when working with SDL surfaces? It's like telling the milk man that you want for news paper an hour later than usual...

Comment: Yes i feel i dont need it is SDL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cout` and `endl` are in the `std` namespace and must be qualified:

```
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Alternatively, you can use a using declaration:

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

cout << endl;
```